# Hot to solve Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Unable to fetch and internet does not work

Tags: dual-boot, 22.04, internet, .desktop, reinstall

I have PC with dual boot with Windows 11 (which works fine) and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. For some reason one day linux booted only to 'terminal mode' without GUI. I purged ubuntu-desktop and then tried to install it again.
I wrote sudo `apt-get --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`. However, it shows 'Unable to fetch some archieves' ([see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoFCw.jpg)). The same goes with `apt-get update`.

I think the problem is because I have trouble connecting to the internet, because `ping 8.8.8.8` gives Network unreachable. Also `ip route` show doesn't show anything. On Windows internet works fine.

Do you know what should I do?

Note: I don't mind reinstalling Ubuntu, but I would prefer not to, since I have data there and it would be more convinient to just solve this problem.

Thank you in advance.

Edit: The PC is connected via Ethernet.

Comment: Is the computer connected by Ethernet cable or WiFi? Add this information in your question. Without knowing the reason behind why "Linux booted only to 'terminal mode'" it is hard to tell you what to do. The easiest thing would be to copy all your personal files to a second empty USB drive after booting from a live Ubuntu installation USB drive (the first USB) and selecting the "Try before installing" option. Once you have copied all the files to the second USB. You should safely remove the second USB and then click on the "Install Ubuntu" icon.